# RDP to a Surface Pro 3

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I use RDP a lot, and with the normal Remote Desktop application I can work from home on my office PC, or from my office on my home PC (which are separated by 30 miles) as though I were sitting at the computer's own keyboard.

However, if I try to RDP to my Surface Pro 3, even when it's sitting on the desk alongside me, the performance is *awful* - the latencies can be several seconds and I may as well not bother trying to scroll the screen with the mouse. If anything, things have got slightly worse since I upgraded my Surface Pro and my home PC to Windows 10, though since doing that I haven't noticed any difference with my other RDP connections (the office PC is still on Windows 7).

I've got an inkling that the reason may be connected with the much higher-resolution screen on the Surface Pro and the way that is is being rescaled during RDP, since my other observation is that when I RDP to my Surface Pro the screen always looks a lot more blurry then when I'm doing other RDP sessions. Yet I can't find a way to rectify this. I normally select "Full Screen" resolution which seems to scale the full desktop to my monitor size (1920x1080, which is quite a bit smaller than the Surface Pro's native 2160 x 1440). Selecting a lower screen resolution in the Remote Desktop application gives me a smaller window with scroll bars, but the same size text.

I've tried using the standard Windows Remote Desktop Connection application (which has been around since Windows 7), the new Remote Desktop (Preview) App from the Windows 10 App Store, and the venerable Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.2 application; in none of them can I find a way around this.

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Before connecting to your Surface, in the Remote Desktop Connection client, edit the properties of your connection and specify that you're using a low bandwidth connection. Then connect and report back if you notice any performance difference.

Comment: That... is really weird. Remote Desktop shouldn't ever be scaling an existing desktop; from the OS' perspective, it's as if you just connected a new graphics card with a new monitor on it, and switched off the old card. The native resolution of the built-in display should be irrelevant. Also, for what it's worth, scaling is one of the easiest things for a GPU to do. In any case, I've had no problem RDPing into a Yoga 2 Pro (similar CPU and GPU, but even higher resolution).

Comment: @Twisty, if I set the connection speed to "low speed broadband" (while in fact it's on the same LAN as my desktop computer), then it's *marginally* better than when on 'detect automatically', but still *substantially* worse than when connected to my other computer 30 miles away.

Comment: After some advice from one of the Microsoft forums, I've tried firstly setting my SP3's screen resolution to that of my desktop PC's monitor (i.e. while sitting at the SP3's own keyboard) and *then* doing the RDP. That does in fact seem to be better; there's certainly less latency, and scrolling seems to work. I'll stick with this for a while and see if it's consistent.